# React Native project started with 'expo init my-project' is not able to be pushed to github?

Tags: git, react-native, expo

I am adding all files `git add .` then committing `git commit -m 'first commit'`, and then using these commands to set origin, set main branch and push:
`git branch -M main`
`git remote add origin https://github.com/BeccaN/my-project.git`
`git push -u origin main`

I'm not getting any response to the push, its just hanging. What can I do to debug this further and hopefully find a solution?

EDIT
I tried reinitializing a new repository from my mac laptop and it worked. Original I was using Ubuntu/Linux. Would still love to hear any theories or advice on why it wasn't working before but does work with Mac?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
expo init
```

Adds their .git directory from their repo when first ran.

You need to rebase the commit, delete the hidden .git directory and try again. One way to resolve before pushing to your repo is run the command:

```
rm -rf .git
```

After you `cd` into the project. Also you can reference this on their forum:

https://forums.expo.dev/t/why-is-there-a-git-in-my-expo-project-folder/12710

Comment: Thank you for your response!

Comment: Welcome, It is an annoying factor about expo. I've debated creating an issue and asking for a flag that would remove this feature when using `init`